# I cannot see the Diagrams option on Pycharm Professional which is useful for generating UML class diagrams

Tags: pycharm, uml

As it is explained in the following link at jetbrains:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/class-diagram.html

In order to generate a UML class diagrams I should right-click an item in the Project tool window and then select **"Diagrams | Show Diagram**. However, I cannot see the option Diagrams.

You can see in the below photo that when I right-click on an item, I don't have the Diagrams option.

[image]

I am using PyCharm Professional and also the plugin "Diagrams" is installed on my PyCharm.

Does someone know why I don't see this option in my IDE?